# Notification messages from when I turned on the phone. Where are they?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-j7

My Galaxy j7 shows me notification messages when I turned on the phone (i.e. received messages, phone calls, apps updated, etc.)

Is there a way to see those from the normal interface without having to turn the phone off and back on?

Comment: I believe you are asking for "Recent Notifications" but it is not clear to me if you know about the swipe down feature.

Answer (score 5):

One way it is possible is by using an app - [Toaster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mars3142.android.toaster) or [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) or [Notification Log History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ikvaesolutions.notificationhistorylog)

**Notification History** displays more information

> Notification History records USSD, Class 0 (Flash) SMS, popped dialog, app installation, toasts and notifications. This can be used to:
>
> 1. Backup messages by apps and read them later
> 2. Find out which app pushed annoying status bar advertisement, and uninstall it.
> 3. Auto dismiss USSD and Class 0 dialog (pro version)

**Toaster**

> Records every toast message including the sender package. May be helpful if you get messages and don't know, which app sends it.

**Notification Log History:** It also let's you view deleted notifications!

---

## I don't want to install an app

Go your widget drawer, find the settings app and drop it on your home screen and choose notification log as shortcut ([source](https://www.asoftclicks.com/notification-log-samsung/)). This is possible with recent Android versions and if your device doesn't support, you can try the same trick by using [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) but then you are adding another app, if Nova isn't your preferred launcher

Comment: I could not get Toaster to work and the other apps are essentially logs(useful in some cases.)

Comment: In my Samsung Galaxy S21 with android 14, the no-app method does not work, in agreement with
[this](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/theres-hidden-notification-history-widget-your-android-0277757/).
Long press in home screen > Widgets > ... does not have "Settings".

Answer (score 1):

So it isn't clear to me exactly what you are looking for so I thought I would post what fixed this issue for me.

[Recent Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.libin.notification) displays the recent notifications as if your phone is locked.  It supports swiping to dismiss notifications, clear all, excluded apps, etc...