# Google assistant found a bill I need to pay from my email but I've lost the notification. Where can I find the full list?

Tags: google-assistant

On my pixel there's an app called "google". From there, More -> Settings -> Notifications -> Bills. I can toggle this option on and off but can't find a list of bills it actually found. Is this available somewhere?

The obvious answer is to go trawling through gmail, but I'd like to recover the specific notification and see what google found.

Comment: If you open the "Google" app and select "Updates" button(?) at the bottom it will show you the personalization page: weather, appointments, stock prices, etc. Your bill may show up therein.

Comment: You can try Nova launcher method - https://www.theandroidsoul.com/recovery-lost-and-cleared-notifications/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification messages from when I turned on the phone. Where are they?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171570/notification-messages-from-when-i-turned-on-the-phone-where-are-they)

Comment: Useful ideas. Thanks all! @MorrisonChang the updates section sounded promising but all it's showing me is I have an empty calendar.