# Cannot find which alarm to wake me up

Tags: alarm, android-10, oneplus-6

I am using oneplus 6 with Android 10 in OxygenOS 10.3.3.

In recent 2 days, I was waked up by the mobile alarm at exactly 08:30 am every morning.

However, I cannot find the alarm app which generate this wake-up alarm.

I have checked the recent app, there is no app running recently at around 08:30.

I search my app with the keyword `alarm`, I found 2 app.  I am sure that I does not set the wake up time in these 2 app at 08:30.  Actually, I set the wake-up time to 07:10 for one of the 2 app.

So, I feel quite strange.  Where is the 08:30 wake-up time set ?

Is my mobile hacked ?

Can anyone help me to find out why there is an alarm at about 08:30 am ?

Comment: Search for "clock" in your apps. Also see if [Notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171570/131553) reveal something

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks.  I find a clock app which generate this alarm. I forget that I have set it up.  Very strange, this app does not show up in the recent-app after it ring at 08:30

Comment: Well, you may self answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @beeshyams, I search my app with the keyboard `clock`.

Then, I found an app which set the wake-up alarm at 08:30 am.

Very strange, this app does not show in the RECENT APP list after alarm ringing.

Comment: Some apps (or to be more specific, activity and task) can request [not to appear on the recent app list after closing](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents#apptask-remove).