# How to keep notification badge when dismissing notifications?

Tags: notifications, lineageos, android-10

I am running LineageOS 17.1 (which is based on Android 10). When I receive e.g. an e-mail or a Telegram message, the notification appears as you would expect and the app icon on the home screen gets a notification badge with the number of unread messages.

When I swipe such a notification away, the badge disappears. I have found posts on the internet claiming any of the following:

- This is intended behaviour, system-wide.
- This depends on the launcher.
- This depends on the individual apps and the best way to get the badge to stay is to write to the respective developers.

### Question

**How can I make the notification badge persist until I have actually read the message?**
I'm hoping for some hidden setting, but I'm willing to install some magisk module or if it's easy enough to contribute some code for adding such a setting to lineageOS (though I'm unaware yet of both their guidelines and the complexity of adding such a setting).

### Use Case

On my old phone with android 7.1.1, that was the default behaviour and it was highly convenient.

#### Example Case 1

A friend sends me 20 messages on Telegram. I see in the notification that they are not urgent and swipe the notification away because it is not currently relevant to me and should not clutter my notifications.
After work, when I have the time to reply in detail, I do so. Or rather, I would, if I hadn't forgotten about the messages because there is no indication that they still exist.

For this example case, Telegram explicitly has options under the heading "Badge Counter" called "Enabled", "Include Muted Chats" and "Count Unread Messages". This implies that the app itself would feature the badge independently of the presence of notifications (since muted chats don't generate notifications).

#### Example Case 2

I receive an invoice on gmail. It's something I'll get to later. I don't open the e-mail yet so that it stays unread, and swipe the notification away.

### System Information

- Android version 10
- Build number `lineage_beryllium-userdebug 10 QQ3A.200705.002 5b9e5cef6f`
- rooted
- POCO Launcher 2.7.4.6

Comment: One option could be to use an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) ( I use it), to keep track of notifications even if you swept them away. Of course, it requires an extra step of opening this app to look up //  [other similar options](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171579/131553)// Title of question is probably misleading, since it's not so much to do with retaining badge count after swiping notifications but more to do with knowing the notifications after you swiped them

Comment: @beeshyams Thank you for making me aware of the [notifiction log](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171579/96334) in the settings, so far I only knew of apps like the one you mentioned and the ones I've used tend to be loading for a long time. If there is no way of making the badges stay, I can see myself using this as a workaround.