# Problem of popups in my POCO M2

Tags: xiaomi, toast-notifications

These popups are in my screen from the day I bought my POCO M2 and they last for long time. And when I am doing something else they come in between. They interfare while typing and selecting options. Moreover, they are annoying. Anyone has idea??

[image: These are the type of Popups]

Comment: They are called toasts. What is shown is a system toast (DND related). You can't get rid of them unless your device is rooted // If it is app related toast, you can track, as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171579/131553)

Comment: You are out of luck. Unlike on devices running closed to vanilla Android ROMs, Xiaomi doesn't allow adb user to perform appops operation (needs `android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS` permission). Otherwise, you could have tried disabling (denying) toasts for com.android.systemui (responsible for those toasts).