# Unknown notification in android

Tags: notifications

I noticed an unknown notification android phone (Vivo Z1 Pro). The title of the notification is 'links'. I opened the settings for that notification but couldn't understand which app is causing it.

Can someone help me understand which app is causing it?

The screenshot of setting for this notification is attached.

[image: screenshot of settings page, includes the text "anybox"]

Comment: I am using android 11.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about the "any.box" on the bottom. Is the [Universal search box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=any.box) app having the package name `any.box` installed? Otherwise, try to [browse the notification history](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171570/44325) and [check the package name of the app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/44325). The app "Links" might also be listed on the Android Settings - App (worst case, it's a system app)

Comment: There was an app called "Links" in the app manager. I uninstalled it. The app was named shortcuts in the playstore. I don't know why it was showing as "Links" on my phone.

Comment: Good to hear that you found it. An app can have a different display name on the Play Store and on the device though, so it's not something that's really strange.

Comment: @AndrewT Thanks for the help.