# Can an app bypass notification settings in Settings > Notifications > App notifications?

Tags: notifications, settings

I have a Samsung S21 with Android 14, with Personal and Work profiles.
It keeps issuing (annoying) notification sounds.
I cannot identify which apps are responsible for that, so I cannot customize them.
I will ask several isolated questions so as to not mix-up.

I went to
Settings > Notifications > App notifications > Three dots > Show system apps.
Then I set up all apps in one of the following states:

1. <Allow notifications: Yes> + <Alerts: Silent>.
   Many apps.
2. <Allow notifications: Yes, but fixed, not selectable by the user> + <Alerts: Silent>.
   A few apps.
   E.g., Android Setup, Android System.
3. <Allow notifications: No> + <Alerts: Silent>.
   In this case I guess the second setting is irrelevant.
   Many apps.
4. <Allow notifications: No>.
   No further settings are provided, with a legend "All notifications from this app are blocked".
   A few apps.
   E.g., Android Auto, Arts & Culture.
5. <Allow notifications: Yes> + <Alerts: Allow sound and vibration>.
   Meet, Zoom. Teams in Work profile.
6. <Allow notifications: Yes, but fixed, not selectable by the user> + <Alerts: Allow sound and vibration>.
   Call, Call & text on other devices, Call settings, Carrier communications, Clock, Find My Mobile, Phone, Phone calls, Phone services, Wi-Fi Calling, Wireless emergency alerts, .

I guess that only apps set to 5,6 can issue notification sounds.
Is this correct?
Can an app set to 1-4 bypass notification settings?
E.g., WhatsApp or others that have In-app notification setting.

**EDIT**:
The issue of how to see notification history, which is a separate question (very relevant here) is dealt with in
[Notification history does not seem to show all notifications. Is this correct? How to see them all?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/256214/notification-history-does-not-seem-to-show-all-notifications-is-this-correct-h)

Comment: Have you checked notification history? https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171570/2241

Comment: @Robert - Yes. With strange (and negative) results, see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/256214/notification-history-does-not-seem-to-show-all-notifications-is-this-correct-h).