# Notification history does not seem to show all notifications. Is this correct? How to see them all?

Tags: notifications, settings

In connection with
[Can an app bypass notification settings in Settings > Notifications > App notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/256212/can-an-app-bypass-notification-settings-in-settings-notifications-app-notifi)
(it makes no sense to copy the body of the OP),
to try identifying the culprit of persistent notification sounds, I went to
*Settings* > *Notifications* > *Advanced settings* > *Notification history*.

While I was at that menu, I received a notification.
But the history was not updated (I also closed Settings and opened it again, with no changes).
(And while I am writing this question, it happened again).

My conclusion is that
not all notifications are shown in Notification history.

Is this correct?
Is there a method to identify those "stealth" notifications?

**Related**:

1. [Notification messages from when I turned on the phone. Where are they?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171570/notification-messages-from-when-i-turned-on-the-phone-where-are-they) (see comments).
2. [Notification messages from when I turned on the phone. Where are they?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171570/notification-messages-from-when-i-turned-on-the-phone-where-are-they#comment346685_171579)
3. https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/theres-hidden-notification-history-widget-your-android-0277757/
4. https://www.lifewire.com/see-the-notification-history-on-android-5093657